# Background-image with gradient effect

Tags: css

How I can reproduce this effect?

[image: Image with grandient effect]

Where image is background with a `gradient` and within it there is a `linear` div with the contents transparent and that content does not inherit the `linear gradient` of the main `div`.

So far I did this:

```css
.wrapper_background{
 width: 500px;
 height: 300px;
 background-image: url('http://www.cvc.com.br/media/6016178/galeria-salvador-elevador_lacerda_017-credito-divulga%C3%A7%C3%A3ocvc.jpg');
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
   box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.8); 
 position: relative;
 margin: 50px 0px 80px 0px;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%); 
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;*/ 
 
}

.content{
 width: 80%;
 height: 80%;
 border-radius: 25px; 
 overflow: hidden;
 border: 1px solid black;
 background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper_background">
 <div class="content">  
 </div>
</div>
```

I tried to use the `box-shadow`, but it only allows (as far as I know) adjust the size accordingly. I believe that have better ways to do this.

What better way to do this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this entirely with a semi-transparent border in CSS3:

```css
.wrapper_background {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url('http://www.cvc.com.br/media/6016178/galeria-salvador-elevador_lacerda_017-credito-divulga%C3%A7%C3%A3ocvc.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 50px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper_background">
  <div class="content">
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3jynLgs8/

Comment: Doesn't require an extra element. check this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/3jynLgs8/1/. BTW, the edges have border-radius in OP's explanation.

Comment: Woooow! Veery simple, I was going for a hard way. Thanks so much! @Mr_Green Your example it's even simple. Within the element itself.